# Why is my JSON.parse() failing on iPhone?

Tags: javascript, iphone, json, titanium, titanium-mobile

I am using Titanium for a mobile application. In the application, the server returns JSON data, which is then parsed by JSON.parse(). On Android, it works fine. I also double-checked it to make sure it's valid with http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Here is my JSON data:

```
    {
   "email":"example@mail.com",
   "count":6,
   "0":{
      "id":"146996",
      "user_id":"25069",
      "item":"item1",
      "start_my_day":"none",
      "scheduled":"n",
      "calendar":"none",
      "start":"00000000T000000",
      "end":"00000000T000000",
      "added":"2011-11-30 06:55:47",
      "updated":"2011-11-30 06:55:47"
   },
   "1":{
      "id":"146988",
      "user_id":"25069",
      "item":"item2",
      "start_my_day":"none",
      "scheduled":"n",
      "calendar":"none",
      "start":"00000000T000000",
      "end":"00000000T000000",
      "added":"2011-11-30 06:52:20",
      "updated":"2011-11-30 06:52:20"
   }
   }
```

When i tried to check what i get with:

```
var response = JSON.parse(json, function (key, value) {
    Ti.API.debug('JSON: ' + key + ' <-> ' + value);
    return value;
});
```

it looks like the object "0" is not parsed as it's supposed to be, but its fields are made part of it's parent. Here's the output:

```
[DEBUG] JSON: email <-> example@mail.com
[DEBUG] JSON: count <-> 2
[DEBUG] JSON: id <-> 146996
[DEBUG] JSON: user_id <-> 25069
[DEBUG] JSON: item <-> item1
[DEBUG] JSON: start_my_day <-> none
[DEBUG] JSON: scheduled <-> n
[DEBUG] JSON: calendar <-> none
[DEBUG] JSON: start <-> 00000000T000000
[DEBUG] JSON: end <-> 00000000T000000
[DEBUG] JSON: added <-> 2011-11-30 06:55:47
[DEBUG] JSON: updated <-> 2011-11-30 06:55:47
[DEBUG] JSON: 0 <-> [object Object]
[DEBUG] JSON: id <-> 146988
[DEBUG] JSON: user_id <-> 25069
[DEBUG] JSON: item <-> item2
[DEBUG] JSON: start_my_day <-> none
[DEBUG] JSON: scheduled <-> n
[DEBUG] JSON: calendar <-> none
[DEBUG] JSON: start <-> 00000000T000000
[DEBUG] JSON: end <-> 00000000T000000
[DEBUG] JSON: added <-> 2011-11-30 06:52:20
[DEBUG] JSON: updated <-> 2011-11-30 06:52:20
[DEBUG] JSON: 1 <-> [object Object]
[DEBUG] JSON:  <-> [object Object]
```

From what i see.. it's not what it's supposed to return. I tried to enclose the count in quotes, to change the "0" to "10", but the parsing stays the same.
If you need any more info, please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JSON.parse(str, func)` is called for each property recursively for formatting/replacement purposes. It is not failing, but you should not use it for your needs.

If you want to iterate over the object, you'd better parse the JSON regularly and use a loop:

```
var parsed = JSON.parse(json);

for(var key in parsed) {
    console.log(key, parsed[key]);

    for(var key2 in parsed[key]) {
        console.log("Nested: ", key2, parsed[key][key2]);
    }
}
```

Comment: In my production code, i am not using that function. I just tried to use it for debugging purposes, because i was getting an exception at the JSON.parse() line. However, it turned out that in some cases i was getting this.responseText as undefined.

Comment: @annie: I guess that's a different issue, unless I'm misunderstanding.